# setOnItemLongClickListener not receiving events

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've got this problem that I cannot receive this event, something is blocking it from one of my items in the listView but I don't know what, I checked focus on the item set to false and it not worked. Also check setting the item to be onlongclickable but it didn't work also. What more?

Comment: Please paste your code !

Comment: Do you have any focusables in your list item? something like a button, switch, checkbox or something? These views cause your listitem to become unclickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem with that and set the parent of the layout `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`, this is the list view item layout

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this in your ListView Adapter ,getView() ,

```
 // For onlongclicks

    final View deleteView  = convertView;

    deleteView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

//For Just onClick

 deleteView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
    });
```

Comment: I am doing this but it is not getting to the onClick